# easiest way to add title row to log file

Tags: c#, file, logging, locking

Easiest way that I can add a title row to each of these files. I can't put it in the Log()'s because it would add the title row each time I reference the test.Log()'s
I thought about referencing 3 new int fields and each time I reference a Log1/2/3() it checks the value of the int and if it's 1 then add the title column else don't.I did one below but it seems redundant I figured there must be a better way.

```
public class Test
{

   public static string File1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "test1.csv";
   public static int a = 0;
   public static string File2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "test2.csv";
   public static string File3 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "test3.csv";     


   private static object _lockObj = new Object();


   public static void Log1(string error, string record)
   { a++;
      if(a==1){
        lock (_lockObj)
        {     
          File.AppendAllText(test.File1, "ERROR" + Environment.NewLine)             
            File.AppendAllText(test.File1, error + "," + record + Environment.NewLine);
        }
      }
     else{
          File.AppendAllText(test.File1, error + "," + record + Environment.NewLine);
       }
    }

    public static void Log2(string message)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(test.File2, message + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    public static void Log3(Test c)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(test.File3, c + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to just put a Title row at the top of the file when creating it?  If so, why not have an `if(!System.IO.File.Exists(test.File1)){File.WriteAllText(test.File1,"My Header Line")}`

Comment: Yes but wouldn't if I add that to my method it would add each time I reference the method as well which I only want it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want put a Title row at the top of the file when creating it...

```
if(!System.IO.File.Exists(test.File1)) //if the file doesn't exist
{   //insert your header at the top
    File.AppendAllText(test.File1,"My Header Line")
}
```

This will only append once when the file is first created

Answer (score 1):

You may create a class like this:-

```
public class HeaderOnceAppender : RollingFileAppender 
{
    protected override void WriteHeader()
    {
        if (LockingModel.AcquireLock().Length == 0)
        {
            base.WriteHeader();
        }
    }
```